# replacing list element of character(0) with NA by using is_empty()

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr, rlang

I have a dataframe (`my_df`) with a list called 'house' with `character(0)` in one row.

I would like to replace this value with `NA_character` by using rlang's `is_empty()`. I am aware that there are workarounds by using  e.g. length(x)==0, but I am trying to understand why my approach with `is_empty()` does not work. Grateful for any hint.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              type = c("house", "tent", "treehouse, mainhouse")
) %>% 
  mutate(house=str_extract_all(type, regex("house")))
  
my_df
#>                   type        house
#> 1                house        house
#> 2                 tent             
#> 3 treehouse, mainhouse house, house
class(my_df$house)
#> [1] "list"

my_df %>% 
  mutate(house_mod=modify_if(house,
                             .p = is_empty(house),
                             .f = NA_character_))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `house_mod = modify_if(house, .p =
#>   is_empty(house), .f = NA_character_)`.
#> Caused by error in `probe()`:
#> ! length(.p) == length(.x) is not TRUE

my_df <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(house_empty=map(house, ~is_empty(.))) 
my_df
#>                   type        house house_empty
#> 1                house        house       FALSE
#> 2                 tent                     TRUE
#> 3 treehouse, mainhouse house, house       FALSE

my_df %>% 
  mutate(house_mod=modify_if(house,
                             .p = house_empty==T,
                             .f = NA_character_))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `house_mod = modify_if(house, .p = house_empty
#>   == T, .f = NA_character_)`.
#> ✖ `house_mod` must be size 3 or 1, not 2.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.f` argument should take a function, but you have just passed `NA_character_` directly. Try `~NA_character_` :

```r
my_df %>% 
     mutate(house_mod=modify_if(house,
                                .p = is_empty,
                                .f = ~NA_character_))
#>                   type        house    house_mod
#> 1                house        house        house
#> 2                 tent                        NA
#> 3 treehouse, mainhouse house, house house, house
```